# How to find the place of digits in a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to find the place of a digit-based substring in a string as

```
$str = " test No. 82 and No. 8 more No. 234";
$needle = "No. 8";
```

I tried `strpos` as

```
$index = stripos($str,$needle);
```

but it finds `No. 82` instead of `No. 8`.

Is the simplest way to use `preg_match` with `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`? Does it really necessarily `regex`?

Comment: Why do you need the indices? A regex can do more than just return the indices. What is the final ideal result?

Comment: what does *the place of digits* mean? the left position(index) of each number OR should it be a range with (left boundary, right boundary) for each matched item?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I use it as an offset in another `strpos` to find a substring after the digits.

Comment: Is that an XY problem then? What is the real text you need to get from the above string?

Answer (score 3):

"Regex" approach would be preferable for such complex cases, `preg_match_all` function will do the job:

```
$str = " test No. 82 and No. 8 more No. 234";
preg_match_all("/No\.\s+\d+\b/", $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

According to your additional condition with search `$needle`:
- we should consider the right boundary of the search "needle" by using metacharacter `\b`

```
$str = " test No. 82 and No. 8 more No. 234";
$needle = "No. 8";
preg_match_all("/$needle\b/", $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => No. 8
            [1] => 17
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a regular expression to match the precise sequence pattern. I suggest this apporach:

```
<?php
$subject = " test No. 82 and No. 8 more No. 234";
$pattern = '/No\. \d+/';
$offset = 0;
while (preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset+1)) {
    $offset = $matches[0][1];
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

The output, which of course can be further processed, is:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(6) "No. 82"
    [1] =>
    int(6)
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(5) "No. 8"
    [1] =>
    int(17)
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(7) "No. 234"
    [1] =>
    int(28)
  }
}
```

Depending on your exact requirements you may want to modify the pattern to `'/No\. (\d+)/'` to match exactly the numeric parts. You also will have to adapt the offset line to `$offset = $matches[1][1];` then obviously.